# Prometheus create rules for all accounts

Tags: prometheus

I want to create some complicated function on Prometheus for every account, for simplify let's say that I want to divide sum of rate by average of it, so the rule will look like this:

```
record: requests_my_account1
  expr:
  sum(rate(requests_total{account="my_account1"}[5m]))
  /
  avg_over_time(sum(rate(requests_total{account="my_account1"}[5m]))[1w:])
```

Is it possible to put some placeholder instead of my_account1, so prometheus use every account, which it has stored or at least for manually creating list of accounts, so I don't have to create separate rule for every account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following rule expression:

```
sum by(account) (rate(requests_total[5m]))
/
avg_over_time(sum by(account) (rate(requests_total[5m]))[1w:])
```